# How to find the resultant derivative when I know the outputs of $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this problem:

*Find $h'(1)$ where $h(t)=f(t^{2}-4t,5-4t^{3})$, $f$ is a differentiable function and $f_{x}(-3,1)=2$ and $f_{y}(-3,1)=6$.*

My first thought was how do I find the resultant derivative of the differentiable $f$.

Some tips, or ideas to solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing but an application of chain rule:

Let $x(t)=t^2-4t, y(t)=5-4t^3$. Then $h(t)=f(x(t),y(t))$.

So $\displaystyle \frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{d(f(x(t),y(t)))}{dt}=\frac{\partial(f(x(t),y(t)))}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial(f(x(t),y(t)))}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$.

Now plug in $t=1$. That will give you the answer.

Comment: @EpsiloDelta, $\frac{dx}{dt}=2t-4$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=-12t^2$, but what about $\frac{\partial(f(x(t),y(t)))}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial(f(x(t),y(t)))}{\partial y}$?

Comment: How do I derive them if I don't know the definition of $f$, what I only know is its parameters.

Comment: $\frac{\partial(f(x(t),y(t)))}{\partial x}= f_x(x(t),y(t))$ and $\frac{\partial(f(x(t),y(t)))}{\partial y}=f_y(x(t),y(t))$

Answer (score 1):

$$h'(t) = f_x(t^2-4t,5-4t^3)(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}) + f_y(t^2-4t,5-4t^3)(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})$$

$$= f_x(t^2-4t,5-4t^3)(2t-4) + f_y(t^2-4t,5-4t^3)(-12t^2)$$

$$\to h'(1) = f_x(1^2-4(1),5-4(1)^3)(2(1)-4) + f_y((1)^2-4(1),5-4(1)^3)(-12(1)^2)$$

$$ = f_x(-3,1)(-2) + f_y(-3,1)(-12)$$

$$ = (2)(-2) + (6)(-12) = -76$$